WordPress upload file without seperate upload.php
I'm trying to upload a file with the wp function wp_upload_dir() inside a custom plugin, I need to upload files inside the WordPress default uploads folder without a separate upload.php file. I am unsure if it is possible to do Ajax without a separate PHP file.
the problem with using separate files requires including wp-load.php so I'm looking forward to another pure JS option.
my upload.php
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$location =  "upload/".$filename;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ){
  echo "sucess";
} else {
  echo "failure";
}

I'm using the JS for uploading files
<input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload">
<button id="upload-button" onclick="saveFile()">Upload</button>
  
async function saveFile() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", fileupload.files[0]);
      await fetch('<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>/upload.php', {method: "POST", body: formData});
      
}

Except for this, everything works fine when I choose the manually set folder path. any help is greatly appreciated.

first thing you should know is WordPress functions did not include automatically in custom php files.

you must include or require WordPress functions.
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");

or
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';


I know but I don't want to do it with PHP, I'm looking for a more minimal Ajax option, If it is not possible I will continue with PHP. Thanks.
